# c# passing inline interface like delegate method

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

i',m using this syntax in java:

```
 public interface Interaction
    {
        void onSuccess(String result);
        void onFailure(String error);
    }

    void getData(Interaction interaction)
    {
        //someCode
        interaction.onSuccess("foo");
    }

    void main()
    {
        getData(new Interaction()
        {
            @override
            void onSuccess(String result)
            {
                    //here is sucess part 
            }

            @override
            void onFailure(String error)
            {
                   //here is failure part 
            }
        })
    }
```

i'm new at c# coding. how can i implement that structure in c#? 
does c# support inline instance interface as java?

Comment: No it doesn't. You would need to redesign your API.

Comment: First of all C# doesn't support instantiating an _interface_ and [neither does Java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp)

Comment: ...however if you define a class `Foo` that inherits from `Interaction`, you could have a `Foo (Action<string> onSuccess, Action<string> onError)` constructor

Comment: Another, less reusable, option is to have 2 `Action<string>` parameters to `GetData` and use lambdas in `Main`

Comment: @MickyD can tell more about ```Action``` and how to implement that?

Comment: ...and yet another option is to use [Microsoft Fakes framework's stubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-stubs-to-isolate-parts-of-your-application-from-each-other-for-unit-testing?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to redesign this is to accept two `Action<string>` parameters:

```
void GetData(Action<string> onSuccess, Action<string> onFailure)
{
    //someCode
    onSuccess("foo");
}

void Main()
{
    GetData(onSuccess: result => {
        // success part...
    }, onFailure: error => {
        // failure part
    });
}
```

Another way is to keep the `IInteraction` interface:

```
public interface IInteraction
{
    void OnSuccess(String result);
    void OnFailure(String error);
}

void GetData(IInteraction interaction)
{
    //someCode
    interaction.OnSuccess("foo");
}
```

But have a concrete class `GenericInteraction` that implements `IInteraction`:

```
class GenericInteraction : IInteraction {
    private Action<string> onSuccess;
    private Action<string> onFailure;
    public GenericInteraction(Action<string> onSuccess, Action<string> onFailure) {
        this.onSuccess = onSuccess;
        this.onFailure = onFailure;
    }

    public void OnSuccess(String result) { onSuccess(result); }
    public void OnFailure(String error) { onFailure(error); }
}
```

This way, the caller of the method can choose to either pass in `onSuccess` and `onFailure` "inline":

```
GetData(new GenericInteraction(onSuccess: result => {
    // success part...
}, onFailure: error => {
    // failure part
}));
```

Or pass something else that implements `IInteraction`:

```
GetData(someOtherInteractionICreated);
```

Which is closer to what you could do in Java.